# Redux RTK query invalidatesTags not called after mutation

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've been trying to figure out why tag invalidation is not working and added some logging. The `providesTags` in `getMe` works fine, but `invalidatesTags` in `login` is never called. What might be wrong?

I have a redux RTK query API like this:

```js
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: baseUrl,
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token = getState().auth.token
    if (token) {
      headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    }
    return headers
  },
})

export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQuery,
  tagTypes: ['User'],
  endpoints: build => ({
    login: build.mutation({
      query: code => ({
        url: `auth/login/?code=${code}`,
        method: 'POST',
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => {
        console.log('auth/login', result, error, arg)
        return ['User']
      },
    }),
    getMe: build.query({
      query: () => 'auth/me',
      providesTags: result => {
        console.log('auth/me', result)
        return ['User']
      },
    }),
  }),
})

export const { useLoginMutation, useGetMeQuery } = api
```

`login` is called on component mount when the page is loaded from a callback like this:

```js
const CallbackComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const [login, { isUninitialized, isLoading, isError, data, error }] = useLoginMutation()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUninitialized) login(getCode(location))
  })
  ...
}
```

`getMe` is used in a component like this:

```js
const Header = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated()
  const {
    data: user,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useGetMeQuery(null, {
    skip: !isAuthenticated,
  })

  if (isError) return <span>{JSON.stringify(error)}</span>

  return (
    <nav className="header">
      {user ? <CharacterList characters={user.characters} /> : null}
      {!user || user.characters.length === 0 ? <Login /> : null}
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Turns out the issue was not in any of these places. I had not added the api middleware to my store.

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(api.middleware),
})
```

docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/rtk-query#add-the-service-to-your-store

Answer (score 0):

I had an quite similar issue where the getMe request would throw an HTTP `401` response code when called without an valid session token. Turns out, that removing the `401` on server side fixed the issue.

However, this is not an optimal solution, so instead I figured out, the `providesTags: ['example']` does provide the tag only on success. To also provide it on failure or some other tag use something like this:

```
providesTags:(result, error, id)=> (
  result
    ? ['example']
    : (error?.status === 401 ? ['UNAUTHORIZED'] : ['UNKNOWN_ERROR'])
)
```

Although you found your solution to the problem already, this might help someone else running into similar issues.